# Finding Z given X & Y coordinates on terrain?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, terrain, intersection

I need to know the most efficient way of finding Z given X & Y coordinates on terrain. My terrain is set up as a grid, each grid block consisting of two triangles which may be flipped in any direction. I want to move game objects smoothly along the floor of the terrain without "stepping." I'm currently using the following method with unexpected results:

```
double mapClass::getZ(double x, double y)
{
    int vertexIndex = ((floor(y))*width*2)+((floor(x))*2);

    vec3ray ray = {glm::vec3(x, y, 2), glm::vec3(x, y, 0)};

    vec3triangle tri1 = {   glmFrom(vertices[vertexIndex].v1), 
                            glmFrom(vertices[vertexIndex].v2),
                            glmFrom(vertices[vertexIndex].v3)   };

    vec3triangle tri2 = {   glmFrom(vertices[vertexIndex+1].v1), 
                            glmFrom(vertices[vertexIndex+1].v2),
                            glmFrom(vertices[vertexIndex+1].v3) };

    glm::vec3 intersect;

    if (!intersectRayTriangle(tri1, ray, intersect))
    {
        intersectRayTriangle(tri2, ray, intersect);
    }

    return intersect.z;
}
```

`intersectRayTriangle()` and `glmFrom()` are as follows:

```
bool intersectRayTriangle(vec3triangle tri, vec3ray ray, glm::vec3 &worldIntersect)
{
    glm::vec3 barycentricIntersect;

    if (glm::intersectLineTriangle(ray.origin, ray.direction, tri.p0, tri.p1, tri.p2, barycentricIntersect))
    {
         // Convert barycentric to world coordinates
        double u, v, w;
        u = barycentricIntersect.x;
        v = barycentricIntersect.y;
        w = 1 - (u+v);

        worldIntersect.x = (u * tri.p0.x + v * tri.p1.x + w * tri.p2.x);
        worldIntersect.y = (u * tri.p0.y + v * tri.p1.y + w * tri.p2.y);
        worldIntersect.z = (u * tri.p0.z + v * tri.p1.z + w * tri.p2.z);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

glm::vec3 glmFrom(s_point3f point)
{
    return glm::vec3(point.x, point.y, point.z);    
}
```

My convenience structures are defined as:

```
struct s_point3f { GLfloat x, y, z; };
struct s_triangle3f { s_point3f v1, v2, v3; };
struct vec3ray { glm::vec3 origin, direction; };
struct vec3triangle { glm::vec3 p0, p1, p2; };
```

`vertices` is defined as:

```
std::vector<s_triangle3f> vertices;
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the intersect of a ray (which is positioned at the x, and y coordinates specified facing pointing downwards toward the terrain) and one of the two triangles on the grid. `getZ()` rarely returns anything but 0. Other times, the numbers it generates seem to be completely off. Am I taking the wrong approach? Can anyone see a problem with my code? Any help or critique is appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**
After considering what David Cummins has suggested, I can confirm that the ray and the triangle should *always* be intersecting. I added some debugging code to visualize the data. The area shaded red contains the two triangles, and the blue line is the line/ray being checked for intersection. Depth has been disabled when drawing the line.

[image: screenshot]

Here is an example of data being passed to [`glm::intersectLineTriangle()`](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00179.html):

```
triangle #1: 
v1={x=19.0000000 y=34.0000000 z=2.70000005}, 
v2={x=19.0000000 y=33.0000000 z=2.70000005},  
v3={x=18.0000000 y=33.0000000 z=2.70000005}

triangle #2:
v1={x=18.0000000 y=33.0000000 z=2.70000005},
v2={x=18.0000000 y=34.0000000 z=2.70000005},
v3={x=19.0000000 y=34.0000000 z=2.70000005}

ray origin:
{x=18.5000000 y=33.1871414 z=10.0000000}

ray direction:
{x=18.5000000 y=33.1871414 z=-10.0000000}
```

Despite passing seemingly reasonable arguments, it always returns false. Leaving `barycentricIntersect` as `{x=0.0 y=0.0 z=0.0}`. Am I misusing the function? Are the values I am passing invalid, and I'm just blind to it?

**EDIT 2:**
I've written a quick [SSCCE](http://pastebin.com/60G7be6K). I would be *extremely* grateful if someone could help me debug this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31844/checking-for-collisions-on-a-3d-heightmap

Comment: Possibly the ray you define isn't guaranteed to intersect with the triangles (e.g. origin is too high/low), or you are experiencing floating point issues with the edges of the triangles.

Comment: Try normalizing your dir vector before passing it in. Functions like this almost always expect a normalized vector, and anything else could cause problems.

Comment: Ray origin and direction have the same coordinates. Shouldn't the z coordinate be negative in direction vector for a ray to point down?

Comment: You're right! I'm sorry, that was a mistake in the post. The actual z value for ray direction is -10.0. See the SSCCE.

Comment: The only thing I can think of are those ray direction coordinates. I don't know how exactly =glm::intersectLineTiangle= works internally, but thinkng about a ray direction vector, coordinates should be in a form of a (0, 0, -x) for it to point exactly down from a origin point.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I stepped over a SSCCE couple of times to understand how it works and these are the clues I found:

* there's a typo in tri2 definition - first two vertices have the same coordinates. I've changed second one to (18.0000000, 34.0000000, 2.70000005) for testing purposes.

* given vertices form triangles with clockwise windings. This states, by default, that both triangles are turned away from a ray's direction. I've reversed ray's direction so the ray shoots up from below triangles.

* I think only dir vector should be normalized in normalizedIntersectRayTriangle function call.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for taking the time to do that. I really appreciate that. After your changes does it yield any results? Is there anything else I should experiment with?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11504/discussion-between-helbreder-and-sparky)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to take care of:

1. Direction of a ray vector in accordance to triangle windings
2. Actual representation of a ray vector

ad. 1)

Seems like `gml::intersectLineTriangle()` function needs a ray vector to point to a front face of a CCW triangle to work.

This is not the case in Your code and You can do two things to fix it: originate a ray vector "below" floor triangles in Your scene (pointing up) or slightly change order of vertices when preparing data for `gml::intersectLineTriangle()` function.

As for the second solution, swapping any two vertice coordinates when preparing data for Your `intersectRayTriangle()` function should do the trick, something like this:

```
vec3triangle tri1 = {   glmFrom(vertices[vertexIndex].v1), 
                        glmFrom(vertices[vertexIndex].v3),
                        glmFrom(vertices[vertexIndex].v2)   };

vec3triangle tri2 = {   glmFrom(vertices[vertexIndex+1].v1), 
                        glmFrom(vertices[vertexIndex+1].v3),
                        glmFrom(vertices[vertexIndex+1].v2) };
```

ad. 2)

Ray direction vector should be a vector originating in (0, 0, 0) as we're interested in actual direction information. I'm not sure if it should be normalized or not, but tests I've conducted over a normalized version yelded valid results.

When constructing parameters for a ray, try this:

```
vec3ray ray = {glm::vec3(x, y, 10), glm::vec3(0, 0, -1)};
```

(applied along with a second solution to ad. 1) or this:

```
vec3ray ray = {glm::vec3(x, y, 0), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1)};
```

(when not).