# Möller-Trumbore false positive

Tags: c++, collision-detection

I've implemented the Möller-Trumbore algorithm but I hit some false positive:

```
Ray: vec3(2.100000, -1.000000, 3.314214), vec3(0.685786, -1.000000, 1.900000)
Collide with: vec3(1.000000, 1.000000, -0.999999), vec3(0.999999, 1.000000, 1.000001), vec3(1.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000))
uvt=vec3(0.435307, 0.198000, -1.603999)
```

If I draw the collision, I see clearly that the ray does not intersect with the triangle.

From this site: http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/moller-trumbore-ray-triangle-intersection
I wrote this code:

```
bool Node::rayIntersectTriangleDebug(const glm::vec3 orig, glm::vec3 dir
                       , const glm::vec3 vert0, const glm::vec3 vert1, const glm::vec3 vert2
                       , glm::vec3 &result)
  {
    //dir = glm::normalize(dir);

    const glm::vec3 edge1 = vert1 - vert0;
    const glm::vec3 edge2 = vert2 - vert0;
    const glm::vec3 pvec = glm::cross(dir, edge2);
    const float det = glm::dot(edge1, pvec);

    const float Epsilon = std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();

    if (det > -Epsilon && det < Epsilon)
      return false;

    const float invDet = 1.0f / det;


    const glm::vec3 tvec = orig - vert0;

    result.x = glm::dot(tvec, pvec) * invDet;
    if (result.x < 0.0f || result.x > 1.0f)
      return false;

    const glm::vec3 qvec = glm::cross(tvec, edge1);

    result.y = glm::dot(dir, qvec) * invDet;
    if (result.y < 0.0f || result.x + result.y > 1.0f)
      return false;

    result.z = glm::dot(edge2, qvec) * invDet;

    const float abs = std::abs(result.z);
    const float dist = std::abs(glm::distance(orig, dir));

    const glm::vec3 intersection = vert0 + result.x * edge2 + result.y * edge1;

    if (abs < dist)
      {
         return true;
      }
     return false;
  }
```

Also I'm not sure if I have to normalize my direction vector.

EDIT

I've red [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/65723/finding-z-given-x-y-coordinates-on-terrain) that

> I'm not sure if it should be normalized or not, but tests I've
>   conducted over a normalized version yelded valid results

I've tried to normalize my direction with the following code without success:

```
const glm::vec3 dir = glm::normalize(officialDirection - orig);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I though that the vector t could be positive if the ray faced the triangle or negative if the ray was in the back of the triangle but this is *not* true. It's positive if you are hitting the triangle and negative if not.

Here is the working implementation:

```
  bool Node::rayIntersectTriangleDebug(const glm::vec3 orig, const glm::vec3 dir
                       , const glm::vec3 vert0, const glm::vec3 vert1, const glm::vec3 vert2
                       , glm::vec3 &result)
  {
    const glm::vec3 edge1 = vert1 - vert0;
    const glm::vec3 edge2 = vert2 - vert0;
    const glm::vec3 pvec = glm::cross(dir, edge2);
    const float det = glm::dot(edge1, pvec);

    static const float Epsilon = std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();

    if (det > -Epsilon && det < Epsilon)
      return false;

    const float invDet = 1.0f / det;


    const glm::vec3 tvec = orig - vert0;

    result.x = glm::dot(tvec, pvec) * invDet;
    if (result.x < 0.0f || result.x > 1.0f)
      return false;

    const glm::vec3 qvec = glm::cross(tvec, edge1);

    result.y = glm::dot(dir, qvec) * invDet;
    if (result.y < 0.0f || result.x + result.y > 1.0f)
      return false;

    result.z = glm::dot(edge2, qvec) * invDet;

    const float abs = std::abs(result.z);
    const float dist = std::abs(glm::distance(orig, dir));
    const glm::vec3 intersection = vert0 + result.x * edge2 + result.y * edge1;


    if (result.z < Epsilon)
      return false;

    /* Convert the barycentric coordinate to wold Cartesian ones: */
    //const glm::vec3 intersection = vert0 + result.x * edge2 + result.y * edge1;


    return true;
  }
```

This implementation works and does not need to have a normalized direction.
I convert barycentric coordinate to wold position with this formula:

```
const glm::vec3 intersection = vert0 + result.x * edge2 + result.y * edge1;
```