# How to find the closest point on a plane

Tags: c#, unity

So I have this terrain with a perpendicular plane setup, now I want to move the vertices of the plane to their closest resp. vertices on the terrain. 
I made a drawing to illustrate my [thoughts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABBww.jpg). 
Final result being the terrain will look like it has some thickness.

i also need the [projection of the point on the terrain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak3Gk.jpg)

I found this code on a previous thread :

```
    float distance = PointToPlaneDistance(smallObj.transform.position, wall.transform.position, wallNormal);

    private float PointToPlaneDistance(Vector3 pointPosition, Vector3 planePosition, Vector3 planeNormal)
    {
        float sb, sn, sd;

        sn = -Vector3.Dot(planeNormal, (pointPosition - planePosition));
        sd = Vector3.Dot(planeNormal, planeNormal);
        sb = sn / sd;

        Vector3 result = pointPosition + sb * planeNormal;
        return Vector3.Distance(pointPosition, result);
    }
```

The result vector here is the closest point

But what is the plane normal? 
Unity has a built in `mesh.normals` which gives all the surface normals for the terrain. Which one should I use here?

Answer (score 1):

Since your plane is perpendicular, you wouldn't use the normals. Just like your second drawing in your album:

[image]

Just ignore the Y and Z axis, of the terrain. For each point you want to match on the terrain, take the X axis value, and match that value on your perpendicular plane.

For example, if the point is at (1,3,0), just take the point (1,planeTop,0) on your plane.

Your terrain even appears to be a regular grid, meaning you can use a simple loop to iterate through the terrain vertices and match them with your plane vertices.

As for the projection, you don't have a flat plane, which is what that code is for. You have an uneven mesh. Using the normals will not help you. Just take the four values that make up the corners of the grid square you're directly above, then use linear interpolation to find the y value of the mesh at that point.

See [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31844/checking-for-collisions-on-a-3d-heightmap/31861#31861) for more information.

Comment: i should have mentioned it before the plane has to move back and forth and fit to the terrain accordingly like this (http://imgur.com/8La7bMa), so i am raycasting from each vertex on the top of my plane and get the point it is hitting on the terrain.

Comment: That only changes the Z coordinate. So, in my example, in your loop, iterating over x: `(x,planeTop,zDepth)`. It's still just one loop.

Comment: this is the code for [it](http://pastebin.com/QTLwtkRt)

Comment: i am converting the vertices to world coordinates before raycasting and replacing the y coordinate with hit.y, finally converting back to the local space

Comment: Yep. Sounds overly complicated. Do you understand my answer?

Comment: :),  yes i understood your answer. Now if i have a case where my plane is in between two rows of the terrain [vertices](http://imgur.com/ZXsqtmk) i am thinking it is better to go with projection. In the answer you suggested, they were talking about barycentric coordinates which are what i need but the world space and local space stuff is confusing me.

Comment: See the answer I linked. You can use that for when a plane is between two rows as well (though, are you actually going to have an edge between two rows? Since then your terrain doesn't look like a solid chunk, I imagine you'll always have a row of vertices above your perpendicular plane).