# How can I move an object on a non flat surface in vulkan?

Tags: graphics, geometry, obj, vulkan

I am writing a small "game" in vulkan, in which a car can move in an environment that is not flat, like a desert with valleys.

I am able to translate my car and follow it with the camera on a flat horizontal plane, however I can't figure out how can I understand if there is a downhill or an uphill and rotate my car consequently.

I was thinking to create a sort of matrix in which for each point I have the eight in thet point and so I can add an offset to the car, and rotate it approximating a plan with the neares points, but I have an obj file, and I don't know how I can proceed.

EDIT:
I am developing a 3d app, in which the car moves in a terrain like the one I link here: https://3dmdb.com/en/3d-model/cycles-mountain-shader-vol-1/1031398/?free=True&q=mountains+displacement

I have created a displacement map with blender of the terrain, in this way I can understand how height I am with respect to the zero, while moving on the map.

I read the corresponding pixel of the height map, which changes from 0 to 255, and I retrieve if I am "high" or "low".

I would like to know if my idea is correct and, moreover, how can I increase the precision; in fact even with the height map I can't be precise, since let's say the value 125 doesn't mean that I'm exacly at half of the total height, for may experiance trying this option, at least.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on where you want to go with this, you could rely on a physics engine to do those calculations. The physics engine controls the world in a realistic way, and your own graphics engine displays it.

Comment: I must use just vulkan, for a university project. I was thinking to use height maps, but they doesn't seem too precise

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and tell us a bit more about what you have so far (including if it's 2d or 3d), that would help us help you.

Comment: Ok, I have update the quastion with how I am proceeding, if you can help it would be great

Comment: Do you have a mesh for your terrain? How do you currently move your car?

Comment: Yes, I have two obj files, one that is the terrain and one the car. I have a vec3 that contains the poisition of the (center) of the car and I move it with matrix multiplications

Comment: I don't know how I would do it "in vulkan" because I have not done any vulkan yet, and I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "in vulkan", but I think you're close to something. An option would be to query your mesh instead of a generated, less precise height map, in a way similar to what is described [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/31844/33287); you do it three times: two for the position of the rear wheels and once for the position of the centre of the front of the car. Then it gives you the plane equation you use to orient your car.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to read something